# Limit questioning using timer

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, timer

How would I approach this.

My idea is to limit posting with a timer. So for example,
if a user posts a question, the user will have to wait 'X' ammount of time before the user can submit another question.

I am using Meteor as my framework. I am not asking for anyone to write up the code FOR me.

I am studying by myself, and I couldn't find any tutorials/tips on what I approach I should take to accomplish this.

Any references, or pointers would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you!!!

(As of now, I am using a Meteor Method to postInsert into the mogoDB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the browser, when the user posts a question, you can disable the controls for posting another question and then use `setTimeout(fn, x)` to set a timer for `x` milliseconds from now at which time your `fn` function can then re-enable the controls to allow them to post again.  Ideally, you'd probably also provide some advice on screen about how much remaining time before they can post again.

To prevent a simple browser refresh from re-enabling the controls, you could also store the time when the next post is allowed in a cookie and read that cookie whenever the page is loaded to decide if the posting controls should be enbled or not.

But, since client protections are not entirely secure (they can be bypassed, sometimes even by just opening another browser), you may also want to record the time of last post in the user session on the server whenever a user posts.  If a new request to post arrives, you can check the time of the last post and decide if enough time has elapsed to allow the post or not.  This assumes you have some sort of user-identifying information which you can use to know when this user last posted.  If not, you would need to add such information.

Comment: Thank you so much! I vaguely have an idea on how I should plan my code!